# Create multiple data frames using pandas data reader in loop

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to create multiple data frames using for loop with pandas data reader and yahoo_finance.I have a list, with each entry being a company name:

`Brazilian_stock_list = ['AALR3.SA','ABCB4.SA','ALSO3.SA','ALUP11.SA','AMAR3.SA','ANIM3.SA', ....]`

I want to create a data frame for each entry on the above list.

- What I've tried to do without success:

```
for stock in Brazilian_stock_list:
     exec('{} = pdr.get_data_yahoo()'.format(stock))
```

- I also tried to remove ".SA" from each entry of above list, but it doesn't work either:

```
Brazilian_stock_list_2 = [stock.replace('.SA', '') for stock in Brazilian_stock_list]

for stock in Brazilian_stock_list:
    ('{}'.format(stock1) for stock1 in Brazilian_stock_list_2) = 'pdr.get_data_yahoo()'.format(stock)
```

Thank you in advance for any help you provide me.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to get the OHLC values of multiple stocks in a data frame, so I propose the following code.　Multiple stocks can be retrieved at once by combining stock issues with blanks.

```
import yfinance as yf

Brazilian_stock_list = 'AALR3.SA ABCB4.SA ALSO3.SA'

data = yf.download(Brazilian_stock_list, start="2020-11-01", end="2020-11-30")

data.head()
           Adj Close         Close           High         Low         Open  Volume
    AALR3.SA    ABCB4.SA    ALSO3.SA    AALR3.SA    ABCB4.SA    ALSO3.SA    AALR3.SA    ABCB4.SA    ALSO3.SA    AALR3.SA    ABCB4.SA    ALSO3.SA    AALR3.SA    ABCB4.SA    ALSO3.SA    AALR3.SA    ABCB4.SA    ALSO3.SA
Date                                                                        
2020-11-03  10.24   12.70   22.379999   10.24   12.70   22.379999   10.41   12.70   23.700001   9.85    12.39   22.219999   9.89    12.39   23.490000   470000  605000  1533600
2020-11-04  10.57   12.61   23.459999   10.57   12.61   23.459999   10.57   12.86   23.510000   10.09   12.47   22.400000   10.38   12.86   22.549999   341600  712800  1162900
2020-11-05  10.88   12.77   24.420000   10.88   12.77   24.420000   11.00   12.89   24.500000   10.60   12.60   23.680000   10.67   12.73   23.809999   333600  723800  3193900
2020-11-06  11.08   12.63   25.030001   11.08   12.63   25.030001   11.13   12.96   25.110001   10.64   12.55   23.790001   10.64   12.71   24.219999   310800  717600  1061000
2020-11-09  11.08   13.31   27.820000   11.08   13.31   27.820000   11.53   13.53   27.900000   11.01   13.05   26.530001   11.43   13.15   27.000000   434900  1084000     3779300
```